# Docker Compose with multiple .yml files and same shared network not resolving container names to ip adress

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two docker compose `yml` files. Both should use the same network. First is the backend project with database, second a Angular frontend.

I tried the follow:

*BACKEND*

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  ....... MySQL and so on

  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - explorer-docs-net

networks:
  explorer-docs-net:
    name: explorer-docs-net
    external: true
```

*FRONTEND*

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  frontend:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
    networks:
      - explorer-docs-net

networks:
  explorer-docs-net:
    name: explorer-docs-net
    external: true
```

Normally when all in the same `yml` file I can call a API in the frontend like this: `http://backend/api/test` (with *Axios* as example) and the **backend** will be converted to its current container IP by docker. If I use 2 `yml` files docker do not resolve the container name and a error occurs like this:

[image]

If I call `docker inspect network explorer-docs-net` the result looks good:

```
....

  "Containers": {
            "215cb01256d8e4d669064ed0b6026ce486fee027e999d2746655b090b75d2015": {
                "Name": "backend",
                "EndpointID": "0b4f7e022e38507300c049f43c880e5baf18ae993e19bb5c13892e9618688353",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1a:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.26.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "240cfbe158f3024b90fd05ebc06b36e271bc8fc6af7d1991015ea63c0cb0fbec": {
                "Name": "frontend-frontend-1",
                "EndpointID": "c347862269921715fac67b4b7e10133c18ec89e8ea230f177930bf0335b53446",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1a:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "172.26.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
....
```

So why docker do not resolve my **container name** when using more `yml` files for one shared network?

Comment: I have already. And its only one explorer-docs-net network there. And inspect the network you can see above - backend is available, frontend, too

Comment: The error message looks like a browser. Your browser is running on the host network. It doesn't know `backend`. You need `localhost` or you have to configure it in `/etc/hosts`

Comment: If you run a backend and frontend in two containers, compose will manage it. So localhost is not the way. You can read about it in docker compose docs. You can use the "container name" in your app and all outgoing requests will be handled by docker. It works. But not with multiple docker-compose.yml files

Comment: Compose won't manage it on your host system and your browser runs on the host system, not in a container. The frontend container doesn't have a connection to the backend container. The browser loads the frontend and opens a connection to the backend.

Comment: Oh man... You're right! The browser itself need to handle it with `localhost`. I had to know it.... Thx for your idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser runs on the host system, not in a container. The frontend container doesn't have a connection to the backend container. The browser loads the frontend and opens a connection to the backend.

You have to use the hostname of the host system in the frontend. Either use `localhost` or configure the hostname `backend` in `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: Yes. In browser is `localhost` the right thing.